# Laplace transform of a modified generalised logistic function

Tags: functions, laplace-transform

I am loking for a Laplace transform of such time function: $\displaystyle\frac{a}{\sqrt{t}\left(1+\exp(-bt)\right)}$ (where $a>0$ and $b>0$ are the constants).
I am not familiar with the LaTeX so sorry for the programming form of equation.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: If we expand $(1 + e^{-t})^{-1}$ into series, we get
$$\mathcal L[t \mapsto t^{-1/2} (1 + e^{-t})^{-1}](s) =
\sum_{k \geq 0} (-1)^k \mathcal L[t \mapsto t^{-1/2}](s + k),$$
which has a closed form in terms of the Hurwitz zeta function.